# Diff between java 6 & 7 for Enum<? extends 'Interface'>

Tags: eclipse, generics, enums, java-7, java-6

My workspace for java dev is Java6,Eclipse. On another machine doing tests with Java7. Problem is behavior of Enum with generics that I can't explain to myself. On java 6 eclipse report error in editor or during compile time but with java 7 no errors and app is working just fine.
Case:
First is trivial interface:

```
public interface TestCase {}
```

then I implement it in several enums like this

```
public enum TcaseFirst implements TestCase {a1,a2,} 
public enum TcaseSecond implements TestCase {a3,a4,}
```

In the main enum  I do initialization of some private EnumMap variables like this:

```
public enum TableC {

private static EnumMap<TableC,Enum<? extends TestCase>> box_1 = new EnumMap<TableC,Enum<? extends TestCase>> ();
...
}
```

When doing java 6 compile eclipse report error:
"type parameter ? extends `Enum<? extends TestCase>` is not within its bound"

And in second case when I modify enum TableC to:

```
public enum TableC {

private static EnumMap<TableC,Enum<TestCase>> box_1 = new EnumMap<TableC,Enum<TestCase>> (TableC.class);
...
}
```

eclipse editor report error:
"Bound mismatch: The type TestCase is not valid substitute for the bounded parameter `<E extends Enum<E>>` of the Type `Enum<E>` "

In third case when I use java 7 and compile same code no error ?!

I can't figure out why this diff.
I can't find on web nothing about this behavior, is it new in java 7, can I trust that java 7 doing correct compile ?

Comment: I don't get any compile error like you mentioned, but the `EnumMap` class has no constructor without arguments. You should at least pass `TableC.class` as argument to the `EnumMap` constructor. Other than that, I don't get any errors regarding use of generics (on neither Java 6 nor 7). Can you post a minimal code sample that gives the problem?

Comment: don't forget, the eclipse compiler is not the standard java compiler.  what does `javac` give you for these cases and versions?

Comment: You both gave me a hint to test this code with javac, without Eclipse. Because I doing apps on JavaEE I always compile through Eclipse. I'll test and post results with and without Eclipse for java 6 and 7. @Martin, I checked this hint and now I know that Eclipse have private java compiler which is not javac from OS (I never thought about that before). Papers for enum and generics are very clear what should I expect. Example link [link](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeParameters.html#FAQ106).